# all possible sublists of a fixed length in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I generate all possible sublists of a given length from a list.

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
```

from this, I want to generate a list of length 5 with all possible unique combinations with no dupes within sublists.
    sublists= [1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,5,6,7]....

Thanks
Suji

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools

l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25] 
list(itertools.combinations(l, 5))
```

Also, don't use `built-in` such as `list` to name your variables.

Comment: is there an option to add a filter to this.. say all sublists which add upto n ?